# Unity - Leap Motion : Prevent hands from going through objects

Tags: unity-game-engine, leap-motion

I'm working on a VR Unity project and I've been asked to prevent the LeapMotion HandModels from going through objects you cannot interact with.

Im new to Unity and LeapMotion so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think this is a bit of a ridiculous requirement because unless you also have physical objects that will prevent a user's hand from going through something, you will end up with virtual hands that are somewhere else than the user's real hands. That will be really confusing.

Comment: Okay so maybe my question did lack a bit of information : There will be physical objects that correspond to the environment of the game.

Comment: So you are saying you run this project with a 3D model of your environment and everything is aligned in game and real space?